# Plotting polar plots with Python: Changing the central point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made the following plot below:

[image: Polar plot]

with this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection = 'polar')
ax.plot(radians(g_long), distances, 'r.')
ax.set_ylim(0.0, 16.0)
ax.set_theta_offset(-0.5*pi)
ax.grid(True)
```

I am trying to 'shift' the centre point from where it currently is at (r, theta) = (0,0) to (r, theta) = (8,0) in accordance with my transformed graph.

I haven't been able to find a solution so far, sadly.

Comment: why not just `ax.set_ylim(8.0, 16.0)`?

Comment: Because it'll just 'condense' everything within a circle of radius 8 into one point.